# Connect to site hosted on Windows Machine by domain name

Tags: networking, windows

I'm trying to connect to a Windows Machine-hosted website on our network. Let's call the Windows machine `server` for ease.

I ran a script I made that returns machine name based on an ip address search.

(just to further clarify: `nmblookup -A "$i"`)

Using that I tracked down the correct IP address for the machine and I can connect to it like this:

> 192.168.1.XYZ/site-name

but it would be really handy to connect to it (like everyone else on the network who uses a Windows machine) by

> server/site-name

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved almost immediately, came to the quick realisation a host entry will solve this.

step 1:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

step 2:

```
192.168.1.XYZ    server
```

now I can access via `server/site-name`